# How to copy a single file AND it's directory name to another location?

Tags: rsync, cp

How would one copy only a single file from a directory to another location, while maintaining the directory name as well? I've gone through the man page for `cp` and tried the different parameters like `--parent` and `-R -r` but didn't seem to do what I want.

I have to work on a single file (`contigs.txt`), and I have 100s of directories that have different names, but all the files within them have the exact same name.

For example:

```
sample_id2300
   |_ file1.txt
   |_ file2.txt
   |_ contigs.txt


sample_id3430
   |_ file1.txt
   |_ file2.txt
   |_ contigs.txt


sample_id4054
   |_ file1.txt
   |_ file2.txt
   |_ contigs.txt
```

In order to not accidentally overwrite the `contigs.txt` file when doing my manipulations on that file for each sample, I'm working on it in a different location so I just want to copy over `contigs.txt` BUT keep it in the directory that has the idname. So something like:

```
sample_id2300
   |_ contigs.txt


sample_id3430
   |_ contigs.txt


sample_id4054
   |_ contigs.txt
```

The other thing I tried is the `exclude` flag in rsync, but then I have to list out all the files I don't want and it still didn't give me the directory name as well.

Comment: Did you consider the `cp FILE DIRECTORY` syntax ?

Comment: Oh no! I didn't think of trying this - I was assuming it wouldn't work because the files I want to transfer over had identical names so was having issues with my loop.